# How to Use NodePort in Custom Kubenetes Cluster on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

For training purpose, I'm trying to setup my own cluster on GCP without using GKE.

I hafe successfully created a cluster with kubeadm with 2 nodes. I'm running an nginx app and exposed it with NodePort. All my pods and services are running.

`kubectl get nodes -owide`

```
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                       KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master-1   Ready    control-plane,master   4m43s   v1.20.0   10.132.0.2    <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)   4.9.0-14-amd64   docker://19.3.14
worker-1   Ready    <none>                 3m9s    v1.20.0   10.132.0.3    <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)   4.9.0-14-amd64   docker://19.3.14
```

`kubectl get svc -owide`

```
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        37m   <none>
nginx        NodePort    10.102.241.17   <none>        80:30695/TCP   31m   app=nginx
```

Here is my `google_compute_instance` terrafom

```json
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
    name = var.vm_name
    machine_type = "e2-standard-2"
    zone = "europe-west1-b"

    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
        }
    }

    network_interface {
        network = var.network
        access_config {
            // Include this section to give the VM an external IP address
        }
    }

    metadata_startup_script = file("./scripts/bootstrap.sh")

    tags = ["node"]
}
```

Here is my terrafom firewall:

```json
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name = "k8s-node"
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
  name    = "k8s-firewall"
  network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name

  allow {
    protocol = "icmp"
  }

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80", "6443", "30000-32767"]
  }

  source_tags = ["node"]
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

With this config, I can not access my instance with `http://my-instance-ip:30695` ... I have a timeout.

But it's working when I allow all Protocols and ports in my GCP console for my firewall rules `k8s-firewall`.
With all protocol and port allowed, I can access my app properly with `http://my-instance-ip:30695`...

What is the issue with my firewall? For me it's suppose to work when I allow only a range between 30000 and 32767 as k8s uses this range for NodePort services.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have added info about my `google_compute_instance` terraform. I have tagged with `node` also. So it should be good for me. And in my GCP console I can see that my rules have been applied. I really don't see where the problem can be

Comment: Try with `kubectl get nodes -o wide`....this should show the public Ip from your nodes....you should be able to access your `service` with `nodeip:svcport` 

Comment: @Hackerman this is not really the issue. It's more a firewall problem as I can access my node with the IP when I delete all fiirewall rules. plus `k get nodes -owide` does not show external IPs.

Comment: Maybe you need to update your firewall inbound rules, to allow trafic to the port exposed by your node port service 

Comment: Should it be [`target_tags`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_firewall#target_tags) instead of `source_tags`? I think @mario is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is located in the following line:

```
  source_tags = ["node"]
```

Just look at *Source tags* definition:

> Traffic is allowed only from sources with these tags. To enter more
> than one, press Return after each tag name.

When accessing your *compute engine VM* from any IP you don't have `"node"` tag applied on such source IP so your traffic is still filtered out. Your current rule basically says: *allow incoming traffic from all IP addresses but also verify if it comes from sources with `"node"` tag applied. If it does not, deny the traffic.*

Answer (score 0):

`source-tags` does not control traffic on the external IP address. Therefore the default rule is DENY for traffic that does not arrive from another instance.

The only traffic that `source_tags` controls is traffic from other instances.

The goal of your firewall rule is to control traffic going to tagged instances.

**Solution:**

Change `source_tags` to `target_tags`.